# How to translate $value in the output code of a view?

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have created a view in which I'm retrieving a time format, whose output is printed by $value.

Here's my **Value Code:**

```
$node = node_load($data->nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$auction_timeout = $wrapper->auction_timeout->value();
$sub = $auction_timeout - time();
$dtF = new DateTime("@0");
$dtT = new DateTime("@$sub");
return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes');
```

And the **Output code** is:

```
<?php
    print ($value);
?>
```

The output is in English which is something like:

> 35 days, 20 hours, 50 minutes

And I want it as

> 35日、20時間、50分

I couldn't find how to translate it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a ' . t('days') . ', %h ' . t('hours') . ', %i ' . t('minutes'));
```